# Whats the purpose of non shared services in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, coding-style

I understand, that if I use non shared service, I will get new instance everytime I request that service. That will allow me to safely use class properties within such service, what wouldn't be wise if I did that on shared service - it would be bit similar to concurrency issues.

**However, whats the non shared service advantages to the plain old php objects?**

I can think only of getting DI container access inside service object out of box, but that wouldn't be big problem, as I could pass what I need to constructor or setter of POPO anyway.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me personally it comes down to **convenience**. Yes, you can get pretty much equivalent functionality with simple objects. But especially in cases that needs a ton of dependencies, it can be a bit of hassle to pass all of it on every instance you need.

It's easier to just define the service with all the dependencies it needs once, and then simply pass it around as needed. In places where you need your non-shared service you pass only this single service, instead of 10 other dependencies that you need to make an instance of an object.

I guess example in YML, using non-autowiring, would be:

```
services:
    App\NonSharedService:
        autowire: false
        shared: false
        arguments:
            - '@dependency1'
            - '@dependency2'
            ...
            - '@dependency15'

    App\RandomService1:
        autowire: false
        arguments:
            - '@App\NonSharedService'

    App\RandomService2:
        autowire: false
        arguments:
            - '@App\NonSharedService'
```

Now in case of creating PHP object inside, you need to pass all dependencies to both of `App\RandomService#`:

```
services:
    App\RandomService1:
        autowire: false
        arguments:
            - '@dependency1'
            - '@dependency2'
            ...
            - '@dependency15'

    App\RandomService2:
        autowire: false
        arguments:
            - '@dependency1'
            - '@dependency2'
            ...
            - '@dependency15'
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently used non shared services as DI helper for Job service class.

I've a main pipe to handle all the jobs with a `JobInterface`.

Each Job class may or may not have its own dependencies and it's own args.
So doing it the old way would be troube:

```php
$job = new JobA(arg1, arg2); // Argh no DI...
// Do stuff to inject services !!
$pipe->dispatch($job);
```

So I've done something like:

```yaml
services:
...
    App\Job\:
        resource: '../Job/'
        public: true # needed to use $container->get()
        shared: false
```

```php
$job = $container->get(JobA::class); // Hello DI !
$job->init(arg1, arg2);
$pipe->dispatch($job);
```

And I can use the power of DI annotation when needed:

```php
class JobA implements JobInterface
{
    /**
     * @Required
     */
    public function setMyService(MyService $myService)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```